# Subtracting Background From Image using Opencv in Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

The following program displays 'foreground' completely black and not 'frame'. I also checked that all the values in 'frame' is equal to the values in 'foreground'.
They have same channels,data type etc.
I am using python 2.7.6 and OpenCV version 2.4.8

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np

    def subtractBackground(frame,background):
        foreground = np.absolute(frame - background)
        foreground = foreground >= 0
        foreground = foreground.astype(int)
        foreground = foreground * frame
        cv2.imshow("foreground",foreground)
        return foreground

    def main():
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        dump,background = cap.read()

        while cap.isOpened():
            dump,frame = cap.read()
            frameCopy = subtractBackground(frame,background)
            cv2.imshow('Live',frame)
            k = cv2.waitKey(10)
            if k == 32:
                break

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are telling OpenCV to display a 64bpc image. You cast `.astype(int)` which means 'int64' or 'int32' depending on your architecture. Cast .astype('uint8') instead. Your maximum brigthness of 255 looks black compared to the full 64bit range.

Related problem:

```
foreground = np.absolute(frame - background)
```

Integer underflow. The expression `frame - background` does not automatically convert to a signed data type. You need a different data type for such calculations (try float if performance doesn't matter), or find an OpenCV function that handles the whole thing for you.

```
foreground = foreground >= 0
```

Because `foreground` is of type 'uint8', which can never be negative, the result is all ones. Simply insert some `print repr(foreground)` statements to debug such problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background sub tractor provided by opencv itself.
you can find the tutorial [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html).
for example look at the code

```
import numpy as np

import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

replace  `foreground = np.absolute(frame - background)`

with `foreground = cv2.absdiff(frame, background)`